# Problem with Ubuntu virtual

Tags: virtualbox

I am having an error with Ubuntu virtualization.
I have windows 8 and on this, have VirtualBox with Ubuntu 17.04.

Windows 8 VirtualBox, So principal.
[image]

When I want create a VirtualBox on Ubuntu Guests, with Genymotion, The SO say 'this kernel requires an x86-64 CPU but only detected an i686 CPU.

Ubuntu Guests, Virtualbox secondary SO
[image]

Comment: What kind of CPU do you have?

Comment: Why are you trying to install Virtualbox into  a system that is installed already as a guest? You can't install a 64-bit system that way, and it generally makes no sense.

Comment: @OrganicMarble this is my CPU. http://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/productdetails/xps-8700

Comment: Sorry, I am not up to looking at an Espanol web page and digging your CPU stats out of it, in order to answer your question.

Comment: @Pilot6, because on ubuntu guests have applications to work with Genymotion https://www.genymotion.com/, and i need to emulate android machines.

Comment: Install Ubuntu normally, not in VB if you need virtual machines.

Comment: @Pilot6, i need that my main SO be Windows.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu and keep Windows.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, http://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/productdetails/xps-8700

Comment: @Pilot6, you say that the solution is, do i must have ubuntu as main SO?

Comment: *You can install Ubuntu and keep Windows* means dual boot where both OSes are in equal stand. There's no "main". And to reiterate the above, you don't install a VM inside a VM.

Comment: i've continued doing investigation, and the solution is give ubuntu as principal SO. VirtualBox only support one level of virtual machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install a 64-bit virtual machine into another virtual machine.

Maybe you can install a 32-bit OS  this way but it is a very bad idea  because it won't work well.